# Uploading files to amazon S3 and other fields to local server using Django

Tags: django, file-upload, amazon-s3, forms

I'm writing a project in Django that has user uploaded images related to products, so my product model is something like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeighKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I would like to store the images at Amazon S3, since it's pretty cheap and fast. I would, as others, like to avoid the overhead of uploading the file to my server and then to S3. There are some sample code explaining how to upload a file directly to S3 from the client browser.

The issue I see (and I did not find any solution yet) is that I don't have only an image to upload. My object (Product) also has other fields, such as name, description and so on. All the examples I saw use one form for the image only. I would like to have one html form (with image, name and so on) for the user and once the user click on "submit", I would be able to store the data in amazon S3 and then the other info (name and so on), on my local database.

According to the image in http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html using a POST method, it's possible to send data from the client to amazon S3 and my webserver. It's now clear if both situations can be included in the same page (same html form).

According to Amazon docs, It's possible to upload a file and set the redirect ULR when the upload is successful.

1) Is it possible to upload the image to the URL and then redirect to my webserver to store the rest of the information? Does the redirect keep the POST data (name, description etc)? How can I access the name of the file stored in S3?

2) Is there any other way to achieve my goal (besides my option #1)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout django-storages (http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/) it does exactly what you need. 
And you don't have to care about multiple forms/redirects etc etc, it will replace the default file storage backend and just push files to amazon s3 bucket.

It supports several kind of storages and S3 in one among them, I've used for several projects so far and it's really easy to plug in.

Since docs seems pretty dead, here's my configurations:

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''
```

and of course you need to install django-storages

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you sure that it does not upload the file to your server first before sending it to amazon S3? I'm already using django-storages to store static files. Do you know if it's possible to use it with 2 different buckets (one for static,e.g. css, imgs, js) and one for media (user uploaded files)?

Comment: I'm not sure that the upload is not done to my server first, but as everything is on amazon, it should be ok. Regarding separate static and media buckets, I extendeded the S3BotoStorage class to initialize it with 2 different buckets and it solved my problem